# Not able to add flutter package flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0, in debug mode app gets installed and closes immediately

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-login

I want to add Facebook login to my project and whenever I tried to add the package   `flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0`, app gets installed but close with an error log.
My flutter version is `Flutter 2.2.2` and below is the error log.

`E/AndroidRuntime( 5135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime( 5135): Process: example.test.com, PID: 5135 E/AndroidRuntime( 5135): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler(java.lang.String, io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger$BinaryMessageHandler)' on a null object reference E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(MethodChannel.java:119) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.initInstance(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:62) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:56) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at sreeleathers.sapco.com.FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant$Companion.registerWith(FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt:15) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at example.test.com.Application.registerWith(Application.kt:15) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor.lambda$startBackgroundIsolate$0$FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor(FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor.java:206) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.-$$Lambda$FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundExecutor$7nPB27qd1U8VFKzcVHyoZxShBIs.run(lambda) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) E/AndroidRuntime( 5135):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

Can anyone please help me with this?
`

Comment: can you try without versioning like `flutter_facebook_login:`

Comment: I tried in that way, but still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid AndroidX, use `version 1.2.0`.
for AndroidX Flutter projects, use `versions 2.0.0` and `up`.

If you haven't completed AndroidX setup in your Flutter project, your project might not build. The simple solution is adding 2 lines in your android/gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

src: [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login)

Comment: I am already using AndroidX and its setup in my project.
I have done this functionality earlier but in a lower sdk verison, but now I don't know what's the issue.

Comment: you can try with the lower version of `flutter_facebook_login`